# Paint on imageview in android?

Tags: android

Can anyone know how to use fingerpaintApi in Android on existing image view?

this is how i draw a text on the image view in android and i need to draw on the image view with the color dialog box for picking colors ?

Mostly it is like paint where you have image background

```
private Bitmap ProcessingBitmap(){
    Bitmap bm1 = null;
    Bitmap newBitmap = null;

    bm1 = bitmapconv;

    Bitmap.Config config = bm1.getConfig();
    if(config == null){
        config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
    }

    newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm1.getWidth(), bm1.getHeight(), config);
    Canvas newCanvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);

    newCanvas.drawBitmap(bm1, 0, 0, null);

    /*
    String captionString = movabletext.getText().toString();
    if(captionString != null){
        Paint paintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paintText.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paintText.setTextSize(50);
        paintText.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paintText.setShadowLayer(10f, 10f, 10f, Color.BLACK);

        Rect rectText = new Rect();
        paintText.getTextBounds(captionString, 0, captionString.length(), rectText);

        newCanvas.drawText(captionString, 0, rectText.height(), paintText);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "drawText: " + captionString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "caption empty!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    */

    return newBitmap;
}
```